# Get current page's thumbnail URL with active sizes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have two ways of retrieving the current thumbnail URLs implemented in my plugin

```
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
$attachment = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id );
echo($attachment[0])
```

Output : wp-content/uploads/2019/10/image-150x150.jpg

```
 the_post_thumbnail_url()
```

Output : wp-content/uploads/2019/10/image.jpg

But I'm looking for the URL of featured image with the size that is currently used in the article/page.

As an example : wp-content/uploads/2019/10/image-1128x484.jpg

But I wish to be able to retrieve the URL for whichever size is currently being used to display the image on the page/post.

Answer (score 0):

To get the featured image URL, you can use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` and supply the specific size you want as an argument.

```
$img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id,'full');
```

Replace `full` with the size you are looking to add.

Comment: This would work perfectly but I don't actually know which size I'm looking at, it will depend on the website and even perhaps the page/post. I need my plugin to retrieve the current URL (including size modifications) that is being used to display the featured image on the current page/post

Comment: This doesn't make sense, when an image is uploaded to page/post it's uploaded in full size, then the theme decides what size to display, without reading the theme code to find which size you want to implement, you can't do it. The only possible way is by programmatically reading single.php and cover every possible instance of an image and pull the size from there which is not simple.

Comment: The theme decides which size to display, but it can not rewrite the image to another size and URL, can it ? Should the URL not be one of : 
    Thumbnail size (150px square)
    Medium size (maximum 300px width and height)
    Large size (maximum 1024px width and height)
    Full size (full/original image size you uploaded)

Comment: Themes and plugins can always create new image sizes, the possibilities are unlimited.